# Dynamic List and Ng-Repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I pivoted a table and returned it to my `angurlarjs` `controller` through webapi `controller`. Based on how it is returned, the column headers are dynamic.

Question: How do I display it using `ng-repeat` and a `table`?

web-api:

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetPayrollSampleList(int payrollId)
        {
                int schoolId = Convert.ToInt32(UserDataPieces(2));
                int schoolBranchId = Convert.ToInt32(UserDataPieces(5));

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = unitOfWork.FinanceRepository.GetPayrollSampleList(payrollId, schoolBranchId, schoolId);

                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            ExpandoObject dynamicDto = new ExpandoObject();

                            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                ((IDictionary<String, Object>)dynamicDto).Add(column.ColumnName, row[column.ColumnName]);
                            }

                            yield return dynamicDto;
                        }
        }
```

angularjs:

```
 $scope.loadGrid = function (payrollId) {
        dataService.getItems(baseAddress + '/GetPayrollSampleList', { payrollId: payrollId })
                .success(function (data) {
                    $scope.myData = data;
            })
                .error(function () {
                    toastr.error("Error loading payroll");
            });
    };
```

UI:

[image]

Comment: Have you written code first ?

Comment: @Vineet I have already written code down to angularjs.

Comment: What's the object with data? Can you put an example at least?

Comment: @Michelem I have added sample code.

Comment: Also `data` output can help. I mean a sample of data. (I suppose that works)

Comment: @Michelem I have added screenshot of how I want my display to look like.

Answer (score 0):

So you've got $scope.myData successfully pulling back the 2d array, with the first row being the headers? Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joshuaohana/1nhcf4g6/1/

```
<table>
  <tr ng-class='{header:$first}' ng-repeat="row in myData">
    <td ng-repeat="column in row">
      {{column}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How do you add header to it?

Comment: @uikrosoft Updated answer and updated jsfiddle link; styles first row differently with ng-class